# Adding a line to a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to create a bar line chart with matplotlib based on happiness index database.

I would like to indicate the generosity indexes of each of the countries on the secondary y-axis with a line chart. df1['Generosity']

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.bar(df1['Country name'], df1['Ladder score'])
plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
fig.set_size_inches(18, 10, forward=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

```
x=df1['Country name']
y=df1['Generosity']
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2 = plt.plot(x, y,color ='r')
plt.ylabel('Generosity')
plt.show()
```

[image]